# Windows 7 to Windows 10 to Windows 8.1

Tags: license, windows-activation, downgrade

Dell Latitude E6430, that originally came with Windows 7 Pro from Dell. COA says "Windows 7 Pro OA". Successfully updated to Windows 10 Pro when the update was available freely. I now have reasons (don't ask) to want Windows 8.1 on that computer.

Do I have a legit Windows 8.1 Pro license?

Bonus questions:

- Assuming yes to the main question, would it be easier to do with the official media from Microsoft, or with a Dell DVD? Since the Windows 7 DVD from Dell doesn't require activation due to the license being stored in the BIOS, I'm assuming that it might be the same for 8.1, therefore making it easier with a Dell DVD?
- Is there a tool to check what license(s) are stored in a laptop's BIOS, to figure out which versions of Windows can be installed without installing them?

Comment: My understanding is that while you can use a 7 entitlement for 10, it doesn't give you the in-between entitlements.

Comment: You do not. You have an entitlement for 10 and (maybe) downgrade rights to what you had before.

Comment: “Do I have a legit Windows 8.1 Pro license?” - Nope

Comment: “Is there a tool to check what license(s) are stored in a laptop's BIOS, to figure out which versions of Windows can be installed without installing them?” - Yes; But those tools don’t apply to Windows 7; The COA sticker indicates which edition of Windows 7 you have.

Comment: Windows 7 licenses ARE NOT stored in the BIOS nor the ACPI table.

Comment: @Ramhound: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS#SLIC

Comment: Just confirmed what I said.  SLIC != BIOS

Comment: And funnily enough, many who commented here were the same that commented on that one almost two years ago!